# Can a site recover by itself after dropping google page rank for 404 errors?

Tags: google, pagerank, 404, ranking

Recently redid a website and changed the directory / URL structure. I did some .htaccess redirects for the main landing pages - however when reviewing web master tools received 404 errors for the rest of the changed URLs and noticed that Google dropped my site from the #1 position to around the 5th page.

I corrected all the 404s by providing redirects in the .htaccess, resubmitted the site map and tested the google crawl bot.

Will my page regain its rank by itself - or am I going to have to put some time into like I originally did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will regain its ranking as everything that made it rank where it did before is still in place. You just have to wait for Google to pick up all of the changes and include them all in it rankings again. That may take a little while but it will happen.

Comment: Any timeframe on that mate? I have changed the permalinks and everything has gone pearshaped.